# MySQL column with utf16 has issue with LIKE operator and FullText index

Tags: mysql, utf-16, full-text-indexing, regexp-like

I have one mysql table  field with UTF16 encode set on this to store emoji and special symbols of a social media app. When I use LIKE operator substring or position function, it goes to endless run.

What can be fix for same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a [mre] for that

Comment: @nbk   myColumn has collation=utf16, and query is   "select * from myTable  where  myColumn LIKE  varKeyword"